# Can't reach NodeJS site on Azure Web App Linux or Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, azure, azure-web-app-service

Having a real hard time getting my web app deployed on Azure.
I can run npm start and have it compile and run on localhost no problem port 4200.

I can deploy it via git onto Azure and then ssh and npm install everything and compile it there. But no matter what I do going to the site url .azurewebsites.net I always get "Cannot GET /"

I've no idea what I'm missing. This is the structure on the server

```
-~/wwwroot/
   -frontend/
     -angular.json
     -node_modules/
     -src/
       -index.js
       -main.ts
       -index.html
       -app/
       -styles.scss
       -environments/
       -tsconfig.app.json
     -index.js
     -package.json
     -e2e/
     -proxy.conf.json
     -protractor.conf.js
     -tsconfig.json
     -package-lock.json
     -web.config
   -server/
     -app.properties
     -pom.xml
     -src/
     -mvnw
     -mvnw.cmd
```

I'm not sure what all files are relevant at this point but I will paste a few that seem like they might be:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "blah",
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node app.js",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
    "private": true,
    "engines":{"node": "8.10.0"},  
    "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "5.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/common": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/core": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.10-4905443",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/http": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/material": "5.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/router": "^7.1.4",
    "angular-tree-component": "^8.0.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
    "core-js": "^2.6.1",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "ng-treetable": "^1.3.3",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "rxjs": "6.2.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
   "devDependencies": {
     "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.11.4",
     "@angular-devkit/core": "^0.6.3",
     "@angular/cli": "^7.1.4",
     "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.1.4",
     "@angular/language-service": "^7.1.4",
     "@types/hammerjs": "2.0.34",
     "@types/jasmine": "^3.3.4",
     "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
     "@types/node": "^10.12.18",
     "codelyzer": "^4.5.0",
     "jasmine-core": "^3.3.0",
     "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
     "karma": "^3.1.4",
     "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
     "karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
     "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.3.0",
     "karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1",
     "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
     "protractor": "^5.4.1",
     "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.6",
     "ts-node": "3.0.6",
     "tslint": "^5.12.0",
     "typescript": "^3.1.6",
     "webpack": "^4.28.1"
   }
 }
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home';
import { LoginComponent } from './login';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin';
import { LoginGuard } from './guard';
import { GuestGuard, AdminGuard } from './guard';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './not-found';
import { ForbiddenComponent } from './forbidden';

export const routes: Routes = [
 {
  path: '',
  component: HomeComponent,
  pathMatch: 'full'
 },
 {
  path: 'login',
  component: LoginComponent,
  canActivate: [GuestGuard]
 },
 {
   path: 'admin',
   component: AdminComponent,
   canActivate: [AdminGuard]
 },
 {
  path: '404',
  component: NotFoundComponent
 },
 {
  path: '403',
  component: ForbiddenComponent
 },
{
  path: '**',
  redirectTo: '/404'
}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
  })
  export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**proxy.conf.json**

```
{
  "/api": {
  "target": "http://localhost:4200",
  "secure": false
 }
}
```

Am I in need of a web.config?

**UPDATE**

I added the below to the ~/frontend/ and ~/frontend/src/
Also changes the start in the package.json to "node index.js"
Again works as expected running localy and navigating to default port but no change in behavior on Azure.

**app.js**

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
 response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
 response.end("Hello World!");
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 4200;
server.listen(port);

console.log("Server running at http://localhost:%d", port);
```

**Update2**

I made a bunch of changes and got..somewhere...
Changed from a linux to a Windows machine.
Did the NPM Install finagaling

Added a web.config and app.js

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <configuration>
    <system.webServer>        
     <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
         <match url="/*" />
         <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
   </system.webServer>
```

If I put the web.config on root I get a http 500 response.
States something to the effect of "Malformed config file"

If I put it on in frontend dir I get a 403 about directory listing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the "Web App Service" blade is a single port instance, so I would have to separate the Azure frontend from the API. Took a long time to figure this out.

I solved by simply deploying to a full VM and everything worked...

Comment: Could you provide a MS reference site to have this confirmed? I could not find any documentation saying this.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that you cannot reach the port 4200. Most examples I have seen use the following snippet:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
server.listen(port);
```

[Here is the code example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/nodejs-docs-hello-world/blob/master/index.js) from their documentation. By default port 80 or 8080 is set.  I have experienced similar issues with deploying docker containers.

Comment: Hi Jamie - I have also seen that mentioned. Usually in a app.js, this examaple uses a index.js file for that snippet. I do not currently have either of those files in my project. I will try creating it and putting in in the root of frontend/ and see if it makes a difference and will update the question. Only other question is might be, where would I then point to that index.js file? Will post results

Comment: I put that file in both the ~/frontend and ~/frontend/src/ but seems to have made no difference in behavior. Updated question to add this file as it sits in my project. I did notice on the browser console that when it states "Cannot GET /" it is producing a 404, but I imagine that's exactly as expected.